# Recommended way to customize EC2 Scheduling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, scheduling

I would thank for your advice regarding EC2 Scheduling.
My requirements are to stopping the instances only in weekends, without turning them on after.
I mean, the users will have to start the instances manually in weekdays if needed.
In addition, some EC2 that has to be ON on weekends can do it by right tagging.

Thanks,
Scottie

Comment: This can be implemented using loudwatch rules where the schedule can be a cron trigger

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to look into a new offering from AWS, [AWS Instance Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/). It interacts with CloudFormation to set up a schedule configuration. It's a bit more abstract than simply setting a config on an instance, but more scaleable that way. That page that I linked to has a link to a CloudFormation template, which seems comprehensive and easy to read.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! What should I set in dynamoDB for stopping instances only in weekends?